# Accesing UPower battery percentage via DBus in gjs: Access Denied

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dbus, javascript

I am trying to make an extension that displays a notification when the battery level reaches certain value. To get the percentage level I am trying to implement [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gjs/Examples/DBusClient) method, but as I don't have a keyboard with backlight I modified the example to report the battery percentage and the state (if it is charging or not) using the information I found [here](https://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/Device.html#Device:BatteryLevel) abut UPower, and it ended up looking like this:

```
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

// This the D-Bus interface as XML
const batInterface = '<node>\
<interface name="org.freedesktop.UPower.DisplayDevice"> \
    <method name="State"> \
        <arg name="State" type="u" direction="out"/> \
    </method> \
    <method name="Percentage"> \
        <arg name="Percentage" type="d" direction="out"/> \
    </method> \
</interface> \
</node>';

// Declare the proxy class based on the interface
const batProxy = Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper(batInterface);

// Get the /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight instance from the bus
let batInstanceProxy = new batProxy(
    Gio.DBus.system,
    "org.freedesktop.UPower",
    "/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice"
);

// You can use proxy.<method>Sync syntax to 
// call the D-Bus method in a Sync way
print("The percentage is " + batInstanceProxy.PercentageSync());

let loop = new GLib.MainLoop(null, false);
loop.run();
```

But when running `gjs test.js` I get the following output:

```
(gjs:66204): Gjs-WARNING **: 20:35:16.865: JS ERROR: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.689" (uid=1000 pid=66204 comm="gjs test.js " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.DisplayDevice" member="Percentage" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.41" (uid=0 pid=1322 comm="/usr/lib/upower/upowerd " label="unconfined")
_proxyInvoker@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:139:46
_makeProxyMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:164:30
@test.js:28:47


(gjs:66204): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 20:35:16.865: Script test.js threw an exception
```

Can anyone point out what could be wrong here?
I am new to gjs, DBus communication and relatively new to JS, but I have done programming before

Comment: To be a bit more clear, I know that an extension is not made like this. I have the extension skeleton but I want to make this piece of code work before implementing it

Comment: I alos tried to read [this](https://gitlab.com/exalm/gnome-shell-extension-dynamic-battery/-/tree/master/dynamic_battery@exalm) code but I could not understand where the percentage value came from (or the proxy object for that matter). It was more complex than what I want to do